# Rails controller cannot find my template even though it exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
def index
  @welcome = current_user.is_Welcome?
  @title = 'Dashboard'
  if current_user.worker?
    project_in_progress = Project.where(:worker_id => current_user.id, :status => 'Currently     Working')
    @projects_in_progress = project_in_progress.order("id DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 8)
    @bid_invites = current_user.bids.where(:status => 'Invited')
    @project_awarded = @projects_in_progress.where(["updated_at > ?", current_user.last_action])
    @milestone_paid = Milestone.where(:user_id => current_user.id, :status => 'Paid').where(["updated_at > ?", current_user.last_action])
    render :worker_index, :locals => { working_projects: @projects_in_progress, bid_invites: @bid_invites, project_awarded: @project_awarded,
                                       milestone_paid: @milestone_paid, welcome: @welcome }
  elsif current_user.buyer?
    project = current_user.projects.where(:status => ['Hiring Open', 'Currently Working'])
    @open_projects = project.order("id DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 8)
    render :buyer_index, :locals => { open_projects: @open_projects, welcome: @welcome }
  end   
end
```

And i do have these view in the right folder.

this is the error i get

Template is missing

Missing template account/buyer_index.html with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :arb, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "

I really hope this is an oversight on my part ....

Comment: Regardless of where you end up on the rendering bit - this is not a `skinny` controller.  You might consider moving the majority of this code (`where` queries, scopes, logic) to the models/other classes to clean this up.

Comment: Thanks for that comment .. i am in the process of cleaning this up. it's part some codebase that i inherited. i had a single view for this different types of users and the first step was to seperate that out

Comment: it seems to be working now .. i had just deleted my files and recreated them. Thanks for your help Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are absolutely certain your views are in the right place, are they named appropriately? They need to match the handlers in `:handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :arb, :coffee]`

E.g. `app/views/accounts/buyer_index.html.erb`

Comment: my views are named appropriately. This is actually a strange one to me .... hence my reason for posting here..